# I am confused by a solution about the time complexity of fibonacc

Tags: algorithm

```
long fib(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

Although I’ve seen a lot of different solutions，some of them do not make sense to me.
Like this one which is a very popular solution(I paste the whole content to here and thanks for your patience as it will take some time)

> Let’s start by assuming that T(n-2) ≈ T(n-1). Don’t worry about why just yet – this will become apparent shortly.
>
> Substituting the value of T(n-1) = T(n-2) into our relation T(n), we get:
>
> T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-1) + 1 = 2T(n-1) + 1
>
> By doing this, we have reduced T(n) into a much simpler recurrence.  As a result, we can now solve for T(n) using backward substitution.
> To do this, we first substitute T(n-1) into the right-hand side of our recurrence. Since T(n-1) = 2T(n-2) + 1, we get:
>
> T(n) = 2[2T(n-2) + 1] + 1 = 4T(n-2) + 3
>
> Next, we can substitute in T(n-2) = 2T(n-3) + 1:
>
> T(n) = 2[2[2T(n-3) + 1] + 1] + 1 = 8T(n-3) + 7
>
> And once more for T(n-3) = 2T(n-4) + 1:
>
> T(n) = 2[2[2[2T(n-4) + 1]+ 1] + 1] + 1 = 16T(n-4) + 15
>
> We can see a pattern starting to emerge here, so let’s attempt to form a general solution for T(n). It appears to stand that:
>
> T(n) = 2kT(n–k) + (2k-1)
>
> For any positive integer k. We can prove this equation holds through simple induction – for brevity’s sake, we’ll skip this process.
>
> Finally, we can find k and, thereby, solve T(n), by substituting in T(0) = 1.
>
> For T(0), we can see that n – k = 0. Rearranging, we get k = n. Now, substituting in our values for T(0) and k, we get:
>
> T(n) = 2nT(0) + (2n-1) = 2n + 2n – 1 = O(2n)

My question is why it can substitute n with 0. In my opinion, the program will be terminated when n reaches 1 as T(n-2) has been replaced with T(n-1). Hence, it's no possible to get the value of n as 0.

Comment: "it's no possible to get the value of n as 0." --> consider `fib(0)` & `fib(2)`.  In both cases, `n==0` at some point.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  In this solution, fib(n-2) has been replaced with fib(n-1). So ```n==0``` will not happen to fib(2) in this case

Comment: It is possible to call the function you provided with ``fib(0)``. It you want you can also substitute ``fib(1)``, but the return result will be the same, so it doesn't matter for this example.

Comment: o o, When `fib(2)` is called, the code solution has `fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)` and recusively calls `fib(1)` and `fib(0)`.  `fib(positive_even)` eventually calls `fib(0)`.

Comment: For this code, I don't think you need any complicated analysis to see that it's Theta(fib(n)). The code either returns 1, or does an addition of two return values from fib. Since the total of fib(n) must be the nth fibonacci number, there must be exactly fib(n) total `return 1` statements executed, and so exactly (fib(n)-1) additions performed (and so 2fib(n)-2 recursive calls made).

Answer (score -1):

Added a simple cout statement .

Consider the call f(2)

```
long fib(2)
{
    std::cout<<n<<"\n";
    if (2 <= 1)
        return 1;
    else{
        
        return fib(1) + fib(0); --- >     here there are two calls  > fib(1)  will return 1 and secod will be fib(0) which prints 0
    }
        
}
```

> the output for f(2)

```
2
1
0
```

Moreover as Note :

```
return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
```

The statement above doesn't guarantee you the order of evaluation  so for f(2) there is no order whether f(1) will be called first of f(0) will be.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. This could be a comment.